# How to generate test data for a "group by data from other rows" algorithm

Tags: sql, algorithm, testing, greatest-n-per-group, data-generation

***UPDATE:** I'm looking for a technique to compute data for all edge cases of my algorithm (or arbitrary algorithm for that matter).

What i **tried so far** is just thinking about what might be edge cases + producing some "random" data, but i don't know how can i be more sure i didn't miss something real users will be capable of messing up..*

I want to check i didn't miss something important in my algorithm and i don't know how to generate test data to cover all possible situations:

The **task** is to report snapshots of data for every `Event_Date`, but make a separate row for edits that may belong to the *next `Event_Date`* - see Group 2) on input and output **data illustration**:

[image: input and output data illustration]

My **algorithm**:

1. make a list of `event_date`s and compute `next_event_date`s for them
2. join the results to `main_audit_table` and compute the biggest `transaction_id` for each snapshot (Groups 1-4 in my illustration) - groupped by `id`, `event_date` and by 2 options based on whether `transaction_date < next_event_date` is true or not
3. join `main_audit_table` to the results to get the other data from the same `transaction_id`
4. join `costs_audit_table` to the results - use the biggest `transaction_id` that is smaller than `transaction_id` from the result

My **question(s)**:

- How can i generate test data that would cover all possible scenarios, so i know i got the algorithm right?
- Can you see any mistakes in my algorithm logic?
- Is there a better forum for this kind of questions?

My **code** (that needs to be tested):

```sql
select
    snapshots.id,
    snapshots.event_date,
    main.event,
    main.transaction_date as last_change,
    costs.costs as costs_2012
  from (
    --snapshots that return correct transaction ids grouped by event_date
    select
      main_grp.id,
      main_grp.event_date,
      max(main_grp.transaction_id) main_transaction_id,
      max(costs_grp.transaction_id) costs_transaction_id
    from main_audit_table main_grp
    join (
      --list of all event_dates and their next_event_dates
      select
        id,
        event_date,
        coalesce(lead(event_date) over (partition by id order by event_date),
                 '1.1.2099') next_event_date
      from main_audit_table
      group by main_grp.id, main_grp.event_date
    ) list on list.id = main_grp.id and list.event_date = main_grp.event_date
    left join costs_audit_table costs_grp
      on costs_grp.id = main_grp.id and
         costs_grp.year = 2012 and
         costs_grp.transaction_id <= main_grp.transaction_id
    group by
      main_grp.id,
      main_grp.event_date,
      case when main_grp.transaction_date < list.next_event_date
           then 1
           else 0 end
  ) snapshots
  join main_audit_table main
    on main.id = snapshots.id and
       main.transaction_id = snapshots.main_transaction_id
  left join costs_audit_table costs
    on costs.id = snapshots.id and
       costs.transaction_id = snapshots.costs_transaction_id
```

Comment: Can you clarify how this data is modeled, and how you managed to assign those groups?

Comment: @Kodra as for a model - they are *IBM Tivoli Service Request Manager* audit tables (a_workorder with dozens of custom fields) + custom audit tables - without up-to-date documentation and my reverse engineering skills are as good as yours..

Comment: @Kodra the group assignment should be clear from point 2. of my algorithm - if not, please tell me what exactly is not clear so i can rephrase it, thanks

Comment: Are you really storing dates as strings, or is that the 'default' representation of a date on your system (`1.1.2099`)?

Comment: @X-Zero it is, but i guess i will use `DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT())` in the production code, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Common table expressions (CTE) are not only a good way to bury complexity and reduce the duplication of longer SQL snippets, but also an easy way to represent test data as if it came from a permanent table. At the very least, CTEs will focus the major components of your query at the top, allowing you to refer to them by their label throughout the rest of the statement. Graeme Birchall's [DB2 SQL Cookbook](http://mysite.verizon.net/Graeme_Birchall/id1.html) (a well-maintained, free e-book) has some good examples of this and other advanced SQL patterns. Joe Celko is another good source for ideas on how to make SQL do more of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: +1 for a great tip,, but actually i don't have a problem with inserting data into real tables - how can i compute the edge cases that need to be tested? (i can generate a lot of random data and miss a case real users will produce) do you know any technique for this?